How to set up Logwatch configuration overrides?
I've been running Logwatch on a Raspberry Pi for some time and learned a lot from it. I decided to install on a Mac (Intel iMac running Sequoia) via MacPorts.
The Logwatch configuration file
/opt/local/share/logwatch/default.conf/logwatch.conf
says to override default variables by putting them in the following file:
/etc/logwatch/conf/logwatch.conf
However, that directory does not exist. So, I'm lost. Do I need to create that directory or does the override file go somewhere else?

Turns out that on the Mac you need to do this:
   sudo mkdir -p /opt/local/etc/logwatch/conf
   sudo touch /opt/local/etc/logwatch/conf/logwatch.conf

